# c# stackoverflow for some strange reason in elementary code

Tags: c#, sql, exception, stack-overflow

- I have a RoundedSum object which basically checks the price of a product and an integer sum into the DB.
- I have an UnRoundedSum object which basically inherits RoundedSum and overrides the checkinsum function and checks the difference to nearest integer into unaccounted
- The UnRoundedSum calls the checkinsum(productid,int) of base to check the
  price value into DB This is my namespace SumRounding that has 2
  Classes

---

```
namespace DatabasePricing.SumRounding
{
    public class Roundedsum
    {
        public void checkinsum(int productid,int sum)
        {
            //Checks in price in the price table
            //dbobject("price",productid,sum);
            int temp_int = sum;    
        }
    }

    public class UnRoundedSum : Roundedsum
    {
        public void checkinsum(int productid,float sum)
        {
            //Since the sum is a float it will check the difference 
            //into unroundedsum table in the database 
            int intsum = (int)sum;
            float tempfloat = sum - intsum;
            //Check this remaining float into the database under unaccounted
            // dbobject("unroundedsum",productid,tempfloat);                
            //Now call the integer checksum with the integer value
            checkinsum(productid,intsum);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is let us assume a main function i have created for testing rite now since it is not working in my project .Well this is like a testing object for the above classes.**

```
using DatabasePricing.SumRounding;
    namespace DatabasePricing
    {
        class testingrounding
        {
            static void Main() { 
            int product_id = 1;
            float float_value = 1.1f;
            UnRoundedSum obj1 = new UnRoundedSum();
            //This call produces StackOverflow Exception
            obj1.checkinsum(1, float_value);
            int price = 200;
            //I tried with integer value to test RoundedSum object
            //it is still throwing an exception
            //This call also produces StackOverflow Exception
            obj1.checkinsum(1, price);        
            }
        }
    }
```

---

[image: Stack Overflow Exception Image]

---

*When i try to debug it is always caught in checkinsum() before it throws the StackOverflow error.. When i tried debugging it comes back into checkinsum() even after executing it. it keeps coming back for some reason. i dont know what could go so wrong.*

Comment: This is most likely cause by the recursive call to `checkinsum`

Comment: At what point in the execution of your call to UnRoundedSum.checkinsum will it stop calling itself? As there is no terminating case, you're filling the callstack pretty quickly. As an aside, because this is a tailcall, chances are that the same code will go into an infinite loop without causing stackoverflow on x64 jitter

Comment: The method `checkinsum` is recursive.  **You should use Visual Studio to help locate problems like this.**

Comment: There is nothing about C++, so please *do not tag* it as C++.

Comment: i guess im a little confused cos i have been @it for a long time.. maybe all you guys are seeing it right. let me understand all your comments a little better. thanks for the help..

Comment: Strangely appropriate question for this website.

Comment: ya well i got 3 answers in quick time. so im indeed dumb not to figure it out. worked for a cuppla hours, the database had no place to hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# standard states that "methods in a base class are not candidates if any method in a derived class is applicable". In other words, `checkinsum(int,float)` will always be preferred over `base.checkinsum(int,int)` when calling `checkinsum(1,1)` because the former is in the derived class and C# allows an `int` to be implicitly cast to a `float`.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/future-breaking-changes-part-three

Comment: ya sure. u also have my upvote . thanks for the help. i understood what was causing so many 0 entries in my DB now.

Comment: thanks for your explanation and the link to the article. it works for me now.

Comment: is there anyway i can prevent this from happening. as in func(int) base class and func(float) derived class to be different. so when i call func(int) of a derived class object it should not match the signatureof func(float) derived class and go to func(int) baseclass.. how do i prevent this from happening using design ? is it only with int and float or are there other examples 2 ? just curious since u seem to have a grip of my problem exactly.

Comment: @user1974729: C# will only implicitly convert between built in datatypes (int, float, double, char, etc.) and derived classes (i.e. from UnRoundedSum to RoundedSum). The best way to get what you want is to either refer to base.checkinsum explicitly or to choose another method name, such as `checkinsum_float`.

Comment: @user1974729: In my opinion, I think you should reconsider your use of object oriented programming. `UnRoundedSum` might be better off as a separate class (not inherited) from `RoundedSum`, maybe with a shared interface.

Comment: yeah sure i hear u, i mean a Sum class with checkinsum(int,int) and checkinsum(int,float) and checkinsum(int,float) calling the checkinsum(int,int) after making an entry into the DB. i agree,yups.

Answer (score 4):

```
    checkinsum(productid,intsum);
```

should be

```
    base.checkinsum(productid,intsum);
```

In UnRoundedSum class

EDIT: Explination, without the base. (which is go to Base Class, and then call the method there) it will call itself in UnRoundedSum, so it will be an endless loop which will cause the stackoverflow

EDIT2:

After reading your comments I think you want this:

```
public class sum
{
    public void checkinsum(int productid, float sum)
    {
        //Since the sum is a float it will check the difference 
        //into unroundedsum table in the database 
        int intsum = (int)sum;
        float tempfloat = sum - intsum;
        //Check this remaining float into the database under unaccounted
        // dbobject("unroundedsum",productid,tempfloat);                
        //Now call the integer checksum with the integer value
    }
    public void checkinsum(int productid, int sum)
    {
        //Checks in price in the price table
        //dbobject("price",productid,sum);
        int temp_int = sum;
    }
}
```

Then it will do the method you want or it is int int or int float.

Comment: ya well i tried that earlier and deleted it . but when i call obj1.checkinsum(1,20); it still goes and calls UnRoundedSum.checkinsum(1,20) for some reason instead of calling RoundedSum.checkinsum(1,20).. because of this i have an extra entry of 0 value in the database.. yeah with base.checkinsum(productid,intsum) it works but it gives me an extra value from the float. can u help me understand why it does that..

Comment: checkinsum(int,int) is defined only in base for me. i overloaded it with checkinsum(int,float) in derived so i could send the rounded off figure to an unaccounted table and the real int to pricevalue table..

Comment: c# will auto convert the float to an Int if it is required. So it won t give an error either.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite recursive call in `checkinsum`.

You may want to call `base.checkinsum` in `UnRoundedSum.checkinsum`

```
public void checkinsum(int productid,float sum)
{
    //Since the sum is a float it will check the difference 
    //into unroundedsum table in the database 
    int intsum = (int)sum;
    float tempfloat = sum - intsum;
    //Check this remaining float into the database under unaccounted
    // dbobject("unroundedsum",productid,tempfloat);                
    //Now call the integer checksum with the integer value
    base.checkinsum(productid,intsum);
}
```

Comment: ya well i tried that earlier and deleted it . but when i call obj1.checkinsum(1,20); it still goes and calls UnRoundedSum.checkinsum(1,20) for some reason instead of calling RoundedSum.checkinsum(1,20).. because of this i have an extra entry of 0 value in the database.. yeah with base.checkinsum(productid,intsum) it works but it gives me an extra value from the float. can u help me understand why it does that..